# How to guarantee even spread pod distribution across AZ in Kubernetes StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, statefulset

I deployed a K8s **StatefulSet** with 30 replicas (or N replicas, where N is multiple of 3) in EKS Cluster.

EKS cluster is with 3 nodes, one node for one AZ, and I want to *guarantee* with Kubernetes Affinity/AntiAffinity the **equal** distribution of pods across different AZ.

```
us-west-2a (n nodes) -> N/3 pods
us-west-2b (m nodes) -> N/3 pods
us-west-2c (o nodes) -> N/3 pods
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use selectors and default labels which you get from AWS. A simple pod spec example is here

```
topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: "topology.kubernetes.io/zone"
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
      matchLabels:
        app: myapp
```

You can include skew and other options based on the need as described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/

Answer (score 2):

While this is too possible with node affinity, a straight forward way is the use of topologySpreadContraints, here's the k8s [documentation, diagrams and examples](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#api) to see it in action.