# How to deploy pods equally in all availability zones?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

How can I deploy pods equally in all nodes distributed in multiple availability zones in a cluster deployed on AWS

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-cluster-multi-zone-auto-scaling-groups/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to guarantee even spread pod distribution across AZ in Kubernetes StatefulSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70239820/how-to-guarantee-even-spread-pod-distribution-across-az-in-kubernetes-statefulse)